# 1-Factorizations of complete graphs sharing a unique 1-factor

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

The complete graph $K_6$ has 15 1-factors (i.e. perfect matching), and 6 1-factorizations (i.e. partitions of the edges into perfect matching). As you can see on the actual drawings, they have a nice property

> Any two 1-factorizations have a unique common 1-factor.

This fact can also be derived by some counting arguments using the fact that an edge belong to 3 perfect matching in $K_6$, but the picture is self-sufficient.

> **Is this statement still true for $n>6$ ($n$ even) ?**

I didn't think too much about the problem, there might be an obvious why this must/cannot happen. As they are already 6240 1-factorisation of $K_8$ I would expect either a counterexample in $K_8$ or maybe $K_{10}$, or an explanation to why this is happening.

For information, this fact came in handy when triying to build a projective plane from $K_6$ : The points are either vertices or 1-factors. The lines are either edges or 1-factorizations.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n\ge8$ it is possible to construct two $1$-factorisations of $K_n$ that share more than one perfect matching. Take a Hamiltonian cycle. Then it is relatively easy to find two different sets of $1$-factorisations of the remaining edges (I leave this as an exercise). These sets, when combined with the Hamiltonian cycle, produce two $1$-factorisations of $K_n$ with at least *two* common $1$-factors. So the nice property cannot hold for $n>6$.

This argument does not work for $n=6$ because there is only one way to make a $1$-factorisation with the remaining edges.